# Can and Does Commander Data make frequent backup's of his programs and memories?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

We have seen that Commander Data attempted to transfer his memories and programs to the B-4 model in Star Trek Nemisis, and also tranferred his daughter's memories before she died to his circuits. So does and can data make frequent backup's of his programs and memories in case he suffered damage or died?

Answer (score 11):

In order to make a useful backup he'd have to have something to back it up into. As far as I know the only available compatible hardware is other [Soong-type androids](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Data), which would mean, in essence that Data would have to 'kill' them in order to create a backup. However...

> Later, after Picard informed B-4 of Data's death, B-4 started singing a song Data had sung earlier on. It is strongly suggested that Data was "reincarnated" in B-4s body using the memories Data imprinted into his network.

Comment: Just watched Measure of Man, in it Commander Madox said that he would dump Data's programs, memories and subroutines into the main computer core. So in effect, these could mean back up in a way, right?

Comment: @TheByzantine This doesn't necessarily mean he would have succeeded - in fact Data was doubtful enough not to want to go through with it.  So Data himself probably never did, and it's doubtful if he could do it on his own.

Comment: The teleporter buffer should suffice.

Comment: In the comic Star Trek: Countdown (prequel to the JJ Abrams Trek) Data is shown to be alive and well in B-4's body. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Countdown