# What is the processing power of Lt. Commander Data in Star Trek - The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

I overheard some of the kids in one of my programming classes discussing this. I am curious as to what the answer is. What do you guys think?

Comment: @Jeeped I looked it up and did not find anything besides a Wikipedia page. Can you point me in the direction of where you saw it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Data have enough memory or "hard drive space"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/did-data-have-enough-memory-or-hard-drive-space)